# JAudiotagger bug with mp3 files on API27?

Tags: java, android, mp3, jaudiotagger

I have a problem with JAudiotagger on API27(Android 7) of android, when I'm trying to set the tags for my audio file I get this error:
`11-24 00:53:20.363 1518-1926/? E/ID3: skipping huge ID3 metadata of size 22934116`
The relevant code snippet is this:

```
TagOptionSingleton.getInstance().setAndroid(true);    
Tag tag = audio.getTag();
tag.setField(TITLE,"Some title");
tag.setField(ARTIST, "Some artist");
tag.setField(ALBUM, "Some album");
audio.commit();
```

This works just fine on API22 (Android 5.something), and it seems that only mp3 files have this issue on API27.

Thanks in advance for the help!

(audio is an AudioFile from JAudiotagger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is specific to the MP3, I think you would have the same warning if you had read the same mp3 on API22. It is not an error, however I think this must be old version of jaudiotager since I cannot find this message when I search through the source code.

Comment: I'm using v2.2.5, I'll try looking through the code myself, see if I can find something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: Update: It seems that it was a problem with adding an album cover to the track which I did somewhere else outside of my snippet. I'll try with a low res image, see if it helps or try downscaling the current one I have.